# BOSH MySql Deployment timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I am trying to install the MySql deployment using bosh deployment manifest by configuring VIP network. I could execute the bosh mysql deployment without any error but in the final stage of deployment i am getting the timeout error(Error 450002: Timed out pinging to 0f66d2df-e923-42c2-81e4-0e1e1a0c39d3 after 600 seconds) while "Started creating bound missing vms > common/0". I have used the below manifest without HAProxy load balancing,

---

name: cf-mysql
director_uuid: fgfg54253-fgkdsgf-4977dfafsdfg

releases:
- {name: cf-mysql, version: latest}

compilation:
  workers: 1
  network: cf1
  reuse_compilation_vms: true
  cloud_properties:
    instance_type: m1.medium
    availability_zone: us-west-2a

update:
  canaries: 1
  canary_watch_time: 30000-180000
  update_watch_time: 30000-180000
  max_in_flight: 4

networks:
   - name: cf1
    type: manual
    subnets:
    - range: 10.0.0.0/24
      gateway: 10.0.0.1
      static:
      - 10.0.0.16 - 10.0.0.17
      reserved:
      - 10.0.0.2 - 10.0.0.15
      dns: [10.0.0.2]
      cloud_properties:
        subnet: subnet-4545d5r4
        security_groups:
        - Bosh

- name: elastic
  type: vip
  cloud_properties: {}
- name: default
  type: dynamic
  cloud_properties:
    security_groups:

  - default

resource_pools:
  - name: common
    network: default
    size: 1
    stemcell:
      name: bosh-aws-xen-ubuntu
      version: 2427
    cloud_properties:
      instance_type: m1.medium
      availability_zone: us-west-2a
      key_name: MYKeyPair

jobs:
  - name: mysql
    release: cf-mysql
    template: mysql
    instances: 1
    resource_pool: common
    networks:
      - name: default
        default: [dns, gateway]
      - name: elastic
        static_ips: 
        - 52.54.25.44
    persistent_disk: 10240

```
properties:
  admin_username: root
  admin_password: root
  port: 3306
  max_connections: 1500
  cluster_ips: 52.54.25.44
```

cloud:
  plugin: aws
  properties:
    aws:
      access_key_id: fslkjghfljsghLJH
      secret_access_key: pqE/fskglkljfsklghkh
      region: us-west-2
      default_key_name: MYKeyPair
      default_security_groups: ["default"]
      ec2_private_key: ~/my-micro-deployment/MYKeyPair.pem

Error log:

DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: SENT: hm.director.alert {"id":"f1205784-c8d5-457a-ac00-7036585f7987","severity":3,"title":"director - error during update deployment","summary":"Error during update deployment for 'cf-mysql' against Director '6a9032ae-197e-47e9-830b-3e4ca0c44f64': #","created_at":1432044197}
E, [2015-05-19 14:03:17 #4025] [task:20] ERROR -- DirectorJobRunner: Timed out pinging to 0f66d2df-e923-42c2-81e4-0e1e1a0c39d3 after 600 seconds.

TIA..,

Comment: Anyone have idea about this issue to fix ?